# Is there a way to multiply a byte type and a float type value in Java?

Tags: java, byte, multiplication

In `C++` code i have  `unsigned char`'s and if I multiply a 255(0xff) value with 0.5 I'll get 127.But in my java code I can't do that because `byte` is signed.
Code example:

```
byte a = (byte) 0xFF;
System.out.println(String.format("0x%02X ", a));
float b = 0.5;
float c = a * b;
System.out.println(String.format("0x%02X ", c));
```

And the result would be

```
0xff
0x00
```

Is there a way to multiply so I get *7f* , or in `int` *127* and store back that value in a `byte` type variable?

Comment: It can be multiplied by values between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `byte` type is signed in Java.  So the byte `0xFF` represents -1 not +255.  So half of -1 is -0.5 ... which when you convert back to a byte would be either -1 or 0 ... depending on rounding.

You probably should do something like this:

```
byte a = (byte) 0xFF;
float c = Byte.toUnsignedInt(a) * 0.5f;
byte d = (byte) c;
```

Alternatively, you could use integer division:

```
byte a = (byte) 0xFF;
int c = Byte.toUnsignedInt(a) / 2;
byte d = (byte) c;
```

... though that will truncate towards zero (these numbers are positive) rather than rounding.